# parameter name used more than once in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

My project used MS SQL, and postgresql so I can't change my parameter to another name, something like below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfunction( ReservationNo integer)
  RETURNS TABLE("reservationno" integer) AS
$BODY$
begin
    RETURN QUERY 
    select
        
        rr.ReservationNo
    FROM Mytable rr
    WHERE rr.ReservationNo = myfunction.ReservationNo;
end
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100
  ROWS 1000;
ALTER FUNCTION myfunction(integer)
  OWNER TO postgres;
```

But it give me an error

> parameter name "reservationno" used more than once

How can I fix it?

Comment: Why can't you change the parameter _name_? The Postgres code to call such a function is completely different to SQL Server's code, so you can't really use the same code to begin with.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: because code in c# they have been add parameter name reservationno. If I changed I must require to other team change there code. It success on SQL  Server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change it to a SQL function, which doesn't have this problem:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION myfunction( ReservationNo integer)
  RETURNS TABLE("reservationno" integer) AS
$BODY$
  select rr.ReservationNo
  FROM Mytable rr
  WHERE rr.ReservationNo = myfunction.ReservationNo;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE sql stable
;
```

Comment: Thank you. It's really worked. May be I must research about the difference between LANGUAGE sql stable vs LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE

Comment: @HongVanVit: in general if you just want to wrap a SQL query into a function, `language sql` is usually better